# Jquery html data-bind attribute use of its

Tags: jquery

I've come across this kind of codes on my HTML file, Here, i just to want to understand what is this `data-bind` attribute and its `values`(example: `visible: tabs.active().value === 'sourceXml'`). what it does here? Any one kindly explain.

```
<div style="border: solid #ddd; border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px; padding: 16px 12px 8px 12px; margin-top: -20px">
    <div data-bind="visible: tabs.active().value === 'sourceXml'">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'sourceXml', data: sourceXml }"></div>
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: tabs.active().value === 'searchTerms'">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'searchTerms', data: searchTerms }"></div>
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: tabs.active().value === 'outputFormat'">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'outputFormat', data: outputFormat }"></div>
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: tabs.active().value === 'savedQueries'">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'savedQueries', data: savedQueries }"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Clarifying**

1.) **The `data-bind` attribute isn't jQuery -- it is an HTML5 attribute nearly exclusive to knockout.js**  ([source](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html)). Data-bindings allow knockout.js to easily associate variable with DOM elements, apply templating schemes, or even apply conditional styling.

jQuery has a similarly-named `.data()` method that lets you access `data` attributes of elements, but that is not the same thing as `data-bind`.

The [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/) detail more about the `.data()` method, but note that *"as of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object"* (emphasis mine). **This is not specific to `data-binding`. Using `data-binding` in jQuery has no special effects.**

---

**What's The Point?**

2.) The "visible" and "template" bits are just explaining what knockout.js should do with the bound data. There are lots of options, for example one easy-to-understand one is `text` ([source](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html)):

```
<div>My favorite string is: <span data-bind="text: myString"></span></div>
```

Basically we are just preparing to apply a variable `myString` to the page once knockout.js loads the template.

Regarding `visible` the docs say, *"The visible binding causes the associated DOM element to become hidden or visible according to the value you pass to the binding"* ([source](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html)).

Similarly, `template` *"populates the associated DOM element with the results of rendering a template"* ([source](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html))

**So your example is checking which template is being used, constructs it in the `div`, and then makes it visible (while hiding the other "unused" templates).**

Comment: It is not exclusive knock out js