# Data-bind works fine but retrieving DOM value with jQuery gives "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding

I have several DOM elements, bound to an object that I retrieve via API call.

I.e

```
<input id="max_row_abs_discount" 
       name="settingsHelper[max_row_abs_discount]" 
       data-bind="value: settings.max_row_abs_discount">
```

The data-binding works fine (in this instance, the data shown by the input is 1500).

If i try to access the value using jQuery though

```
let testVariable = $('#max_row_abs_discount').val()
```

It gives "undefined" in return.

**EDIT:**

This is my full code where I try to access it:

```
    .on('click', '#change_all_table_settings', function(){
       let testVariable = $('#max_row_abs_discount').val()
    })
```

If the syntax seems weird, it's because I'm using Magento.

Anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) data-binding is done by knockout.js most probably, not jquery (check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885228/jquery-html-data-bind-attribute-use-of-its) for more details); 2) when exactly you're trying to access that value?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still a novice in both jQuery and knockout.
I'm trying to access it later (after the binding is done), through an "onclick" function. When a checkbox is checked, I'd like to retrieve the value and change it to a default value decided by me.

Comment: Why do you want to change the value in DOM (view) and not inside knockout state (Model)?

Comment: Because I have to send the new info using a form. 1) Can I do that using the knockout state? 2) If I update the value in the knockout state, does the DOM updates itself?

Comment: 1) yes; 2) that's the whole point of using knockout actually.

Comment: I would keep all of my data manipulation inside of Knockout rather than trying to get it from DOM elements.

Comment: @raina77ow your answer to point 2 solved my problem. I didn't know that data-binding was dynamic. The problem to being self-taught I guess, I'm trying to practice first without learning the theory. Chris, yep, that's what I'm going to do. Thanks Chris, and especially thanks to raina77ow!

Comment: Actually I do have an issue now. Using jQuery I could update all the DOM elements with the same class to be the default value...now I'm not sure what to do. Should I update manually all the elements of the knockout state? That doesn't seem very 2019

Comment: Nevermind. Updating the value using jQuery and then using change() updates the value of the knockout state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might have my problem, knockout makes a lot more sense. 
Accessing with jQuery what is already available in the observable model it's not possible and it's really not the way to go.
Changing the value of the observable did the trick for me.